# Displaying permanent table\list of printf()

Tags: c

I want to display a string of characters in table\list. The table\list is made of printf function.

**For Example**:  `printf("|---------|") or`something like that.

I want to know is there any chance of displaying the size of the table\list permanent no matter what user input and then display it in the table.

Sample output is in the image below.

[image]

Code:

```
  printf("------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("|  Name: %s                               |\n",p_array[i].name);
```

How to lock those horizontal lines in `printf()` no matter how long output will be.

Comment: Read *carefully* the documentation of various [stdio](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) functions, including of `snprintf`. But SO is not a *do-my-work* service.

Comment: And it would be easier to help you to fix your code if you only *show* it... You really should read [ask] because this question is currently *off topic* on this site.

Comment: I apologize, that was my first post on this site. Do it too fast without research, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` allows you to pad your output. For example

```
printf("|%-20s|", str);
```

You can see more details by reading up about padding for printf.